# curl error - 79 Error in the ssh layer

Tags: c++, curl, ssh

I am using curl library within c++ code. I would like to upload a file to the server using sftp and user authentization. While I manage to do this from windows command line using

```
curl -k -T f:/temp/openvpn-config.zip -u user:password sftp://fabrika/tmp/
```

calling curl with options

```
struct stat file_info;
FILE *fd = fopen(f:/temp/openvpn-config.zip,"rb");
int res_st = fstat(fileno(fd), &file_info);
fclose(fd);

ffile.open(f:/temp/openvpn-config.zip,ios::in | ios::binary);

curl_easy_setopt(h_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://fabrika/tmp/");
curl_easy_setopt(h_curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(h_curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, (void*)&ffile);
curl_easy_setopt(h_curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, &ReadCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(h_curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);
curl_easy_setopt(h_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(h_curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
```

gives me error code 79, which tranlates into "Error in the ssh layer". I checked the fstat result, the file size passed to curl is correct.

Edit: Forgot to add debug information from verbose mode, here it is

```
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Adding handle: conn: 0x4236ef0
Adding handle: send: 0
Adding handle: recv: 0
Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
- Conn 0 (0x4236ef0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
Trying 192.168.3.1...
Connected to fabrika (192.168.3.1) port 22 (#0)
SSH MD5 fingerprint: 9e73dade666cbbac9a82adfeffbd9f18
SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password
Using ssh public key file id_dsa.pub
Using ssh private key file id_dsa
SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open public key file
Initialized password authentication
Authentication complete
Upload failed: Operation failed (4/-31)
Connection #0 to host fabrika left intact
```

Clearly I am missing some parameter used by the command line curl which does the trick, I'll be grateful for any suggestions.

Petr

Answer (score 11):

**Answer:** I got an answer via curl mailing-list, so here it is in case someone got stuck like me. When uploading files, curl needs full target path, including filename. So

```
curl_easy_setopt(h_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://fabrika/tmp/openvpn-config.zip");
```

did the trick.

Comment: An additional hidden trick. If you don't know the current user path at SFTP server, Curl accepts the caracter '~' as "HOME" variable. So, you can use `sftp://fabrika/~/openvpn-config.zip` to copy directly the file to the path of your SFTP user

Comment: For others coming here with curl error `curl: (79) Upload failed: Operation failed (4/-31)`. This possibly means there is not enough space left on the SFTP you want to put data on. Deleting old and unneccessary files from the SFTP solved the problem for me.

Comment: At least for command-line curl, the destination dir MUST end in a '/' to tell curl that it is a DIR and not a destination file. So, perhaps ending your destination with a slash will do the trick and avoid awkward refactoring when uploading multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your application doesn't have access to read "id_dsa.pub" and so the SSH handshake doesn't complete.
Try to look into CURLOPT_CAINFO

Comment: Do I need to provide that to curl? I understood it as there are two methods of authentication, keys and user/password, and keys failed, whereas user/password succeeded. Also quote from man pages  "If CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is zero, CURLOPT_CAINFO need not even indicate an accessible file"

Comment: Try looking into CURLPROTO_SFTP